# Why am I getting an invalid value error?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, redux

I don't understand how I'm getting this error (pic below).  In my `LoginForm.js` file, the `onEmailChange(text)` is giving me an `unresolved function or method call to onEmailChange()` error when I hover over it in my `WebStorm` IDE.  In my `index.js` file, no error is being thrown anywhere.

I've looked around SO for this issue but it doesn't fully pertain to my problem.

I've tried `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` but that didn't work.

[image]

Here's `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/common/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Provider style={styles.c} store={createStore(reducers)}>
                <LoginForm/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    c: {
        flex: 1
    }
});


export default App;
```

Here's `LoginForm.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {emailChanged} from 'TorusTeensApp/src/actions';
import {Text, StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    render() {
        onEmailChange(text)
        {
            this.props.emailChanged(text);
        }

        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    onsubmitediting={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                    returnKeyType={"next"}
                    placeholder={"Email"}
                    label={"Email"}
                    keyboardType={"email-address"}
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.props.email}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    ref={(userInput) => this.passwordInput = userInput}
                    returnKeyType={"go"}
                    placeholder={"Password"}
                    label={"Password"}
                    secureTextEntry
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Create Account</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20 // creates a gap from the bottom
    },

    userInput: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#9b42f4',
        height: 40
    },

    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#41bbf4',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginBottom: 20
    },

    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = state =>  {
  return {
      email: state.auth.email
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, {emailChanged}) (LoginForm);
```

Here's `index.js`:

```
import {EMAIL_CHANGED} from './types';

export const emailChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: 'EMAIL_CHANGED',
        payload: text
    };
};

export default emailChanged();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export default emailChanged;` ? if you include `()` you are executing the function and exporting an object.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your callback inside your `render()` method and not inside the class body. Do it like this:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    onEmailChange(text) {
            this.props.emailChanged(text);
    }        

    render() {
       return(...);
    }
}
```

Also you shouldn't bind methods inside your `render()` method. Do it in the constructor of your Component:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onEmailChange.bind(this);
    }

    onEmailChange(text) {
        // do something
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Or if you use babel and ES6, you can define your callback with an arrow function, then it will be automatically bound:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {

    onEmailChange = text => {
        // do something
    };

    // other methods
}
```

See also the [react docs about autobinding](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#autobinding).

Also your call to connect seems incorrect. If you want to dispatch the action `emailChanged` it has to look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>  {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    // this put a function emailChanged into your props that will dispatch the correct action
    emailChanged: text => dispatch(emailChanged(text))
}; 

const LoginFormContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);    

export default LoginFormContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to connect needs to be a function that knows how to merge the output of `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`, and `ownProps` all into one object that is then used as props for your connected component. I think you're trying to pass that action to the `mapDispatchToProps` argument, which is the second argument not the third. So, based on what I think you're doing, you probably wanna change your `connect` line to look like this.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {emailChanged}) (LoginForm);
```

Then, export the function from your actions file not the output of calling that function.

```
export default emailChanged;
```

Notice I removed the parentheses so it's not being called.

Then make the callback function a method on your class and bind it in the constructor.

```
constuctor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this);
}

onEmailChange(text) {
  this.props.emailChanged(text);
}
```

Then update `onChangeText` on that element.

```
onChangeText={this.onEmailChange}
```

Comment: I see where you're going but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Make the callback function an arrow function.

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work either.  I'm getting `unused default export emailChanged` whenever I hover over `export default emailChanged;`.

Comment: You'll probably have to make `mapDispatchToProps` a function, then, and wrap your action creator in a function that dispatches the output of calling the action creator.

Comment: Also try making the callback function a method on the class.

Comment: Checkout my answer. I updated it to be a method on the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your connect is miswired

```
connect(mapStateToProps, null, {emailChanged}) (LoginForm);
```

It should be something like:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, 
       (dispatch) => ({emailChanged: (text) => dispatch(emailChanged(text))}) 
)(LoginForm);
```

so that your action actually gets dispatched

and as spotted by emed in comment:

```
export default emailChanged;
```

without parentheses.

Comment: I tried this but whenever I write `export default emailChanged;`  and hover over it, it's giving me a `unused default export emailChanged`.

Comment: It should be without parenthesis period. You also missed whole section how to use connect